# How to run a Runnable on UI thread from a custom class

Tags: android

How can I run a Runable on the UI thread from a custom class? The method "runOnUiThread(Runnable)" would get the job done but it is a part of an Activity. I wonder if the Application class support something similar because its easy to get an instance of it. 
I have read about the annotation "@UiTread" from the androidannotation framework. Does this annotation also work for a custom class?

Comment: may I ask why you don't use an AsyncTask if you need to update something on your main UI thread from another class?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or [View.post(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: If you go with option one: do make sure you create the handler (or pass in a looper that was created) on the UI thread, since the handler gets associated with the 'current thread' - in other words: the thread it was created on.

Comment: There is actually a trick for that. Just pass the main looper to the Handler when creating it. The main looper is the one that runs in the UI Thread. `mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`

Comment: I know, that's what the part in brackets from my previous comments says. ;) Anyways, just thought it might be worth pointing out to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you avoid running a Runnable on the UI thread. About the only reason I can think of to do it is to do some sort of timer that "sleeps" for an amount of time before it exits. In general, you can cause a lot of performance problems by using Threads, Runnables, and so forth outside of the Android framework. Not that they don't work, but then again you may tear your hair out trying to get them debugged.

Instead, to do "background" work, use an AsyncTask or an IntentService.